# onReceive doesn't work on BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I need to know what the user selected in order to share content for analytics. For this, I use the Google ShareSheet.

To obtain the value selected by the user from the Google ShareSheet, I use a PendingIntent. Here's how I've implemented it:

```
...
override fun doOpenShareSheet(
        activity: AppCompatActivity
    ) {
        var flag: Int = PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            flag = PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        }

        val pi: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            activity,
            0,
            Intent(activity, ChooserBroadcastReceiver::class.java),
            flag
        )

        // Implement Google ShareSheet
        val share: Intent = Intent.createChooser(
            Intent().apply {
                action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, config.url)

                // Passing content URI to image to be displayed
                flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                type = "application/url"
            },
            config.mediaTitle,
            pi.intentSender
        )

        activity.startActivity(share)
    }
...
```

Now, to get the value, I need to register the `BroadcastReceiver` dynamically (as I cannot pass the value to the receiver's constructor in the Manifest).

Here's what I have:

```
...
class ChooserBroadcastReceiver(private val vm: MyViewModel): BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val selectedComponent: String = intent?.extras?.get(Intent.EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT).toString()
        vm.doOnChooserBroadcastReceiver(selectedComponent = selectedComponent)
    }
}
....
```

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
...
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        registerBroadcast()
    }

    private fun registerBroadcast() {
        chooserBroadcastReceiver = ChooserBroadcastReceiver(vm = vm)
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            requireActivity().registerReceiver(chooserBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter, RECEIVER_EXPORTED)
        } else {
            requireActivity().registerReceiver(chooserBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter)
        }
    }
...
}
```

However, for some reason, I'm not receiving the value. I can see that the event is happening, and I can choose how to share the content through the Google ShareSheet, but the event is not received in onReceive.

P.S. For the test, I tried removing the view model from the constructor and registered the receiver through the manifest, and everything worked. Here's how:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application>
        <receiver
            android:name=".ui.MyBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

But I need to pass a parameter to the constructor, so this method doesn't work for me.

What am I doing wrong? Why does it work when registered through the manifest, but the event is not received when registered dynamically in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot pass the value to the receiver's constructor in the Manifest

Putting a `ViewModel` in the receiver's constructor is kinda weird. Regardless, your `PendingIntent` and your `IntentFilter` do not match.

```kotlin
        val pi: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            activity,
            0,
            Intent(activity, ChooserBroadcastReceiver::class.java),
            flag
        )
```

This says "look in the manifest for `ChooserBroadcastReceiver` and send the broadcast to it".

```kotlin
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
```

This says "respond to `ACTION_SEND` broadcasts" (which itself is weird, as `ACTION_SEND` is usually an activity action).

You need those things to match. If you do not wish to register your receiver in the manifest, then you need to use a `PendingIntent` that creates an `Intent` that matches your `IntentFilter`.

```kotlin
        val pi: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            activity,
            0,
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND),
            flag
        )
```

Also, please note that on most versions of Android, any app on the system can send a broadcast to that receiver, as it will be exported.

> But I need to pass a parameter to the constructor,

You could use dependency inversion (Dagger/Hilt, Koin, etc.). That may be difficult to get a suitable Jetpack `ViewModel`, but you could inject a repository or use case or something.

Comment: yep, it is actually true, for most of the versions this receiver will be visible as `exported`, however, in this case, I can `putExtra` to the intent as a flag, so I would be able to differentiate between the events, does it make sense?

Comment: @Sirop4ik: Nothing stops an attacker from adding the same extra.

Comment: Oh, that is right, however, broadcast (pendingIntent) is the only way to know what has been chosen by the user (as a share option) from Google ShareSheet.

Comment: @Sirop4ik: Yes, but you could register your receiver in the manifest and mark it as not exported. *You* are the one who decided that you need to use a constructor with your receiver; there are other options, such as dependency inversion.

Comment: yep, agree. Also looks like it is impossible to `putExtra` for `sdk > S` as it forces to use `FLAG_MUTABLE` or `FLAG_IMMUTABLE`, however, these flags don't guarantee that you get the actual value on the other end. It is advisable to use `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` (but as I mentioned it forces to use another value).